# file_exists with 'replace' or 'use existing' not working when a variable is passed

Tags: 8, files, migrations

Can somebody point out the fault in this snippet for downloading a file entity. I am trying to replace or use existing file dynamically using migrate_plus. When I give a variable it doesn't seems to pass to 'download' plugin. If I hard code the value to 'replace' or 'use existing' it works.

```
file_config_keys:
  plugin: default_value
  default_value: "use existing"
uri:
  plugin: download
  source:
    - '@source_image_url'
    - '@dest_image_uri'
  file_exists: '@file_config_keys'
destination:
  plugin: 'entity:file'
migration_dependencies: null
```

Comment: What is that a snippet of? I don't see how a .yml file would force a download myself. There just isn't enough information provided to be able to give a response.

Comment: Update the question. I'm trying to download the file using migrate_plus module. The yml file is migrate_plus.migration.mymodulename.yml

Comment: Don’t you need a dash for each plugin line?